# Does gpu memory need to match motherboard memory?

Tags: memory, motherboard, gpu

I'm currently looking for a gpu upgrade and I've come across the GTX 1650 which has GDDR5 memory in it. My current PC (HP Z2 Tower G4 Workstation) supports DDR4 non-ECC memory and I was wondering if this would be an issue. My cpu is the i7-9700k, I don't know if this was necessary info but just in case!

Comment: If you did have to match them, how could *any* graphics card with GDDR memory ever be used? I don't think there are any motherboards that support GDDR memory of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

No.
If you are are using a separate video-card (as you do) the RAM on the video-card is completely independent and doesn't have to be the same type or speed as the RAM on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

No, the graphics memory that comes with an external GPU is managed by the GPU itself (which has its own memory controller) – not by the CPU – and it's nearly always of a different type than the system memory anyway (hence "GDDR" vs regular DDR).

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with dedicated video controllers they have own dedicated memory which is not connected (directly) with the processor memory. You are free to replace your video controller with any which is supported by your motherboard.